# Debian Mate Desktop Eclipse scoll bar slider button size huge

Tags: debian, gtk, mate-desktop, eclipse

I am on **Debian** Buster, **Mate Desktop** theme Menta, OpenJdk 11.0.9.1, **eclipse 2020-06**.

My scroll bar sliders in eclipse are huge.

[image]

I tried resizing them by a custom gtk-3 css file but this did only change the bar itself but not the buttons. *gedit* does apply the css settings. See bewlo:

[image]

It does not matter if **theming in eclipse** is on or off (I restarted) or the used eclipse theme.

I read about the setting and tried changing `-Dswt.enable.themedScrollBar=false` / `true` in `eclipse.ini`, didn't change a thing.

**gtk-3 css**

The `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` I tried. Pretty much the default values from [GTKTheme](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes/GtkScrollbar)

```css
    scrollbar slider {
      /* Size of the slider */
      min-width: 6px;
      min-height: 6px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      -GtkRange-slider-width: 6;
      -GtkRange-stepper-size: 6;
      -GtkRange-stepper-spacing: 0;
      -GtkRange-trough-border: 1;
      -GtkRange-arrow-displacement-x: 0;
      -GtkRange-arrow-displacement-y: 0;
      -GtkRange-activate-slider: FALSE;
      -GtkRange-trough-side-detrails: FALSE;
    }
```

**gtk-2 gtkrc**

I tried setting `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

```css
    style "scroll"
    {
     GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 6
    }
    class "*" style "scroll"
```

**Side note:** It looks even worse using the dark eclipse theme as the slider colour does not change.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in eclipse, right? You only see the issue in eclipse?

Comment: Sounds like it but it seems strange that only I found it. No other apps so far, it is a rather new system so I don't have too many time to check. I dug into some SWT Code and found the following fishy part, but from around 2013. It is only talking about vertical thogh. https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/gtk/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Slider.java?id=3604d504487ba5ac6629a7341338d0fa513e8af0#n171 and the comment is just great: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475909#c2

Comment: Oh that made me think … those steppers might be a relict and only used in mate themes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to exist only with the stepper buttons which are not really required in my case. They can be disabled and the bar looks okay.

See some unresolved gtk bug report that might be related: [Unresolved Gtk stepper button width bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475909#c2)

The following comment made me think about disabling the buttons:

> Still an issue for GTK2. But less of one for GTK3 since high contrast
> and adwaita don't use stepper buttons by default. However, if you have
> a theme with steppers this is still present in 3.

GtkTheme Reference about disabling the stepper buttons: [GtkTheming](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes/GtkScrollbar#Style_Properties)

This gives me a smaller bar. The colour could be changed as well I guess.

```css
/* Disable steppers as the width is not conforming to the slider width and looks strange in apps like eclipse (SWT) */
scrollbar {
  -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 0;
  -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 0;
}

scrollbar slider {
  /* Size of the slider */
  min-width: 6px;
  min-height: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -GtkRange-slider-width: 6;
  -GtkRange-stepper-size: 6;
  -GtkRange-stepper-spacing: 0;
  -GtkRange-trough-border: 1;
  -GtkRange-arrow-displacement-x: 0;
  -GtkRange-arrow-displacement-y: 0;
}
```

[image: Sliders smaller]

Comment: Nice find! And thanks for taking the time to post your solution :)

Comment: Thanks for being the rubber duck ;-)